# Firebase Auth / Identity Toolkit: Is there an official way to check if an OOB code is valid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firebase-authentication, passwords, google-identity-toolkit

I am building a reset password process in my Rails app and using Firebase Auth's email templates by replacing the default URL with my app's domain. While using the oobCode, everything is working correctly as mentioned in https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v1/accounts/resetPassword.

However, I want to inform the user about the expiration or invalidity of his/her oobCode *BEFORE* attempting to make an HTTP request to change the password.

Currently, I am telling the user about this through the request's response, which is after the call.

Is there any endpoint or way to determine if an OOB code is still valid?
And if it exists, it would be great the response to include the email address involved

Thanks in advance.